# What is correct? Or/For or something else?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct way to write this sentence:

> A: Highest number of goals scored in a single game of 90 minutes: 12
>
> B: Highest number of goals scored in a single game for 90 minutes: 12
>
> C: Highest number of goals scored in a single game __ 90 minutes: 12

Comment: **A** is good. **B** is poor grammar, **C** is poor punctuation. Are there games which are not 90 minutes?

Comment: None is a complete sentence because they have no verb. 'Scored' is an adjective in all of them. As a phrase within a sentence, A is best. I would write, "... goals scored in a single, 90-minute game."

Comment: @RossMurray how is "scored" an adjective?

Comment: I presume C is actually asking for a word to fill in the blank. Please see the [tag info for prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info). We need to know what the sentence is to mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ones that go to extra time, they have a duration of 120 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best preposition to use is *of*, which is your first sentence: *a single game **of** 90 minutes*.

That said, I think a better way to write this would be to turn "90 minutes" into an adjective:

> Highest number of goals scored in a 90-minute game: 12

Answer (score 0):

**A** is your best answer, because the prepositional phrase "of 90 minutes" says that the game is 90 minutes long.  **B** uses the wrong preposition for the phrase, "for" instead of "of", but still gets the point across.  **C** is confusing and should be avoided.  If you want to use punctuation, I suggest:

Highest number of goals scored in a single game (90 minutes): 12

Answer (score 0):

Or, "In games of 90 minutes, the highest number of goals scored is: 12."

Answer (score 0):

The comments from @AndrewLeach and @BoldBen wised me up to filling in the blank: I had thought "__" was punctuation! Presuming the *style* of your sentence is to remain as a summary, my suggestion is

> C: Highest number of goals scored in a single game **lasting** 90
>   minutes: 12

Here the word "lasting" is not a preposition but an adjective, which qualifies **game**.

Comment: Should there be a comma before lasting?

Comment: I don't think so.